# Php dates is not compare properly

Tags: php

I am new in PHP

when I am trying to do this

```
if( date('m-Y',strtotime('2016-11-01 00:00:00')) < date('m-Y') ) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

but it always do false [output 'no'].

I must need to compare months is less than current month , means compare date do not have same months

where I am wrong to compare that date ?

Comment: These are not dates, they are strings. If you want to compare dates, you should compare `DateTime` objects or timestamps.

Comment: @jeroen or dates as string but formatted as Y-m-d

Comment: I must need to compare month , means compare date do not have same months

Comment: This will always return false because you are comparing with current date `date('m-Y')`

Comment: May be `strtotime(date('m-Y',strtotime('2016-11-01 00:00:00'))) < strtotime( date('m-Y'))`

Comment: @AnkitSoni. Please check https://eval.in/713989. You need to change the format `m-Y` -> `Y-m` so that they can be recognized.

Comment: @jeroen I have removed a bunch of your comments because they were drifting into needless discussion based on a wrong premise. Strings actually *are* natively comparable using `<` and `>`. They are *not* cast to numbers. `'a' < 'b'` is `true` while `'c' < 'b'` is `false`. It actually works this way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime` to compare dates:

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-11-01 00:00:00');
$now = new DateTime();

if ($date < $now && $date->format('m-Y') != $now->format('m-Y')) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. OP specifically mentions wanting to compare *year* and *month*.

Comment: No.. he wants to compare the dates but only the month should be different.. I updated the answer

Comment: @DaanMeijer This answer uses the ***exact same*** dates to get the desired result as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your program so that it reads:

```
<?php
$x=date('m-Y',strtotime('2016-11-01 00:00:00'));
echo "$x\n";
$y=date("m-Y");
echo "$y\n";

if ($x < date('m-Y') ) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

On running it the output is:

```
# php x.php 
11-2016
01-2017
no
```

That is why it fails. If you are checking for just the month you need to check for equality. Otherwise you need to reorder the date formatting to be "Y-m" (not 'm-Y') for less/greater than comparisons. Comparing the strings is fine.

Comment: This is pretty much my answer, no?

Comment: @DaanMeijer. Yes, in a little more detail. I was editing it while you answered so I didn't see your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`date` function always return a string. In your `if` construct you compare two strings. For current time:

```
"11-2016" < "01-2017"
```

In this case `"11-2016"` greater than `"01-2017"`.
It will be better to use `DateTime` class.

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-11-01 00:00:00');
$now = new DateTime();

if ($date < $now && $date->format('m-Y') != $now->format('m-Y')) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

or in your example you need to change format to `'Y-m'`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a decent format to compare the dates. Instead of `m-Y`, use `Y-m-d`.

Currently, you are converting the dates to strings, with their months first. So the first date becomes `11-2016`, the second becomes `01-2017`. PHP compares these as strings, and finds that `0` is less thans `1`, so considers the second string to be less.

Comment: Datetime cannot be compared this way.

Comment: Sure they can. When using the right date format, you can compare dates perfectly. Please explain your point of view further.